# import numbers with '-' and scientific notation

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi I'm trying to import and create a table from an excel file.

I have two problems that I'm running into, one is when I import the file as an .xlsx with the import wizard it automatically sets a field to a float and won't let me change it in the "edit mappings" dialogue box.  It then drops the records that have a dash like 389-1145.

If I instead save the file as a .csv and import it with the wizard, it will import the field as a varchar, but the entries which are in scientific notation like 1.1e+11, will be imported as simply '1.1e+11' instead of 110000150192.

I'm sure I'm not the first guy to run into this issue, so any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: 389-1145 is not a number. It is an expression at best. What exactly is the purpose of the column with this value?

Comment: SSIS uses the first few rows of data to determine the data type.  You can inserted a few fake rows at the top of the xlsx, and put text in the cell to trick SSIS into making a varchar instead of a float/int etc.  Then just delete from your new table when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all good question you ask, I had the same problem. What happened while importing excel as per our database design, it consider text to text , number to float and datetime to date-time (in mm-dd-yyyy format).

To overcome first you create a temp table with all data-type as nvarchar, so any junk value entry, that will accepted in db. Now after dataflow, you run a sp (create before to run ssis) which simply transfer your data from temp folder to your actual table with desired dataformat and value which you want.

Use sqltask to run sp in ssis.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f1d17dcc-86ec-4c05-aeb4-e117f5e791f6/how-do-i-call-a-stored-procedure-to-insert-data-in-sql-server-in-ssis-data-flow-task?forum=sqlintegrationservices

http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/OLE-DB-Command-Transformation.aspx